# Liferay - Server has Not Found Anything Matching Request URI

Tags: liferay

I've had several different versions of Liferay including Liferay 6.2 EE which I'm using now, and I still haven't seemed to solve this problem.

Whenever I try to do certain things like save Web Content, create a blog, or change my theme, Liferay just resets and no changes are made.

This is the only noteable error I'm getting in my logs:

10:25:12,497 WARN  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'][code_jsp:154] {code="404", msg="*Error 404--Not Found*

### Error 404--Not Found

#### From RFC 2068 *Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1*:

10.4.5 404 Not Found

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.

_", uri=/monitor/bigip.html} [Sanitized]

I'm fairly certain this is telling me the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it

Any ideas?

Comment: is there any url that we can see?

Comment: There's a domain and a database URL as well as some other ones I'm not sure about, which ones would we need to see?

Comment: the one where this portal is running. when error comes, can you see the logs for any exception/error/message?

Comment: While the portal is running, all i can see is the message above and some 'Accepted connection: filtering - etc." messages. Not noticing any other errors